# Why is std::unique_lock not derived from std::lock_guard

Tags: c++, c++11, language-design, std

`std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` interfaces look very similar, in their common part (constructors and destructor).

Why there is no hierarchical relationship between them?

Comment: why should there be? Merely "looking similar" isn't a very good reason to derive from another class.

Comment: Also, `std::unique_lock` has other semantics: it's a **movable lock**, whereas `std::lock_guard` is a __mainly a guard__. Although both share `lock` in their name, they're meant for different (but similar) purposes.

Comment: @jalf Well, I can see also a semantic correspondence between them. Don't they do the same job, with unique_lock having the possibility to do a lot more? Isn't it a classic example of possible inheritance use?

Comment: @Zeta Yes, unique_lock can do more things. But don't they behave the same for the common part of their interface?

Comment: They do, but the overlap is so small that the number of positive effects is  insignificant. Also, you don't want to have a `virtual` method in a lock, right? That being said, I guess you can get a definite answer by [the authors of `Boost.Thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have non substitutable semantics:
`lock_guard` is guaranteed to be locked through all of it's lifetime.
`unique_lock` doesn't guarantee that so it doesn't follow the "IS A"-rule (`unique_lock` cannot be a `lock_guard`, as it offers fewer guarantees).

Also implementing `unique_lock` based on `lock_guard` wouldn't be trivial (maybe even impossible) for that reason.

Obviously the same is true the other way round: Although you can implement a `lock_guard` in terms of a `unique_lock` (private inheritance), `lock_guard` doesn't provide the same functionality (`lock()/unlock()`) as `unique_lock` so it cannot be publicly derived from it.